# update the answer of a column on group by

Tags: sql

I am working on a query where

| PatientNo. | VisitNo. | DischargeCode | DischargeStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Survived |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | Survived |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | Survived |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | Died |

There is a patient, who visited 4 times in the hospital (visit numbers are 2, 3, 4, 5). If the patient died in the journey of the visits then there should be a fifth column as `PatientFinalStatus` as `Died`.

If the patient survived in the journey, then status should be survived.

So in the case shown above, the fifth column should be `PatientFinalStatus` and the value should be `Died` in all 4 rows.

It should be grouped by `patientno`, and then for each visit number check what is the status. Wherever it finds `died`, it should update the whole column to `Died`, otherwise `Survived`.

Could anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with conditional count window function as the follwing:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN DischargeStatus='Died' THEN 1 END) OVER
                      (PARTITION BY PatientNo) > 0 
        THEN 'Died'
        ELSE 'Survived'
       END AS PatientFinalStatus
FROM table_name
ORDER BY PatientNo, VisitNo
```

If you have only two possibilities for 'DischargeStatus' (Died or Survived), you can simply use `MIN` window function as the following:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(DischargeStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientNo) PatientFinalStatus
FROM table_name
ORDER BY PatientNo, VisitNo
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/11ZqQLRW).